# 3D Graph change of color of a particular region

Tags: python, 3d

I Have created the following Cube and I would like to change the colour at position [15,9,0].

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
cube=np.ones((24,24,4),dtype='bool')
fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes(projection = '3d')
ax.set_facecolor("Cyan")
ax.set_facecolor
ax.voxels(cube,facecolors="#E02050",edgecolors='k')
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


cube=np.ones((24,24,4),dtype='bool')
facecolors = np.full(cube.shape, "#E02050")
facecolors[15,9,0] = "#000000" #black

fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes(projection = '3d')
ax.set_facecolor("Cyan")
ax.voxels(cube,facecolors=facecolors, edgecolors='k')
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

But the face in position `15,9,0` is located on the base of the cube so you can't see it. Try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


cube=np.ones((24,24,4),dtype='bool')
facecolors = np.full(cube.shape, "#E02050")
facecolors[15,9,0] = "#000000"

fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes(projection = '3d')
ax.set_facecolor("Cyan")
ax.voxels(cube,facecolors=facecolors, edgecolors=(0,0,0,.1), alpha=.5) #adding transparency to see the black face on the base
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]